# How to get the DataSource, UserID and Password from an Entity ConnectionString?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, connection-string, bulkinsert

We have an ASP.NET MVC web application that works with Entity Framework. Everything works quite nicely so far, but now I need to implement a function that allows for importing huge amounts of data into an archive table.

The data I need to import comes as a SQL Server Compact database file which I can upload and process through the web application. My first attempt was to read in the rows and create new objects for each row, which I added to a list of that type. Then I used EF's `AddRange()` method for adding the rows to the database.

This method did not work because of memory and performance issues, even with small import files. So I googled a bit and decided to go for an *SQL bulk insert* (and thereby circumventing EF), which was clearly stated as the most performant way.

In my `web.config`, I have the EF connection string, which also contains the data that is neccessary for accessing the database. As I need to work with an `SqlConnection`, I do need a working SQLProvider ConnectionString. The EF connection string does not work in that case because of additional entries that the SqlConnection does not work with (leading to errors like "unsupported keyword: metadata" etc).

So I want to build a new SqlConnection connection string with an `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`. I only need three parameters: UserID, Password and DataSource. All of these are present in the EF connection string.

How can I get them from my existing EF connection? I definitely do not want some ugly parsing/regexing, but I could not figure out how to get these values.

Comment: I know this is not part of the question, but why don't you just add a new connectionstring in the web.config instead of trying to use the existing to build a new?

Comment: You are right, I could simply add another connectionstring, but as the required data is already present, I would like to use the existing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try casting `EntityConnection` to `SqlConnection` directly. This will also give you access to the info you need.

```
 using (var ec = new EntityConnection(connstr.ConnectionString))
 {
     var sqlConn = ec.StoreConnection as SqlConnection;
     sqlConn.Open();

     var dataSource = sqlConn.DataSource;
     var userId = sqlConn.Credential.UserId;
     var password = sqlConn.Credential.Password;
 }
```

Comment: __Remark:__ You don't need to open SqlConnection to get DataSource.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an old question, I'm posting a response hoping that someone else might find it useful.

The accepted answer may not be good for someone who doesn't want to open a connection just to get the properties like Data Source, User Credentials etc.

This is the way I would go about it:

Web.Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Genus_Connection_String" connectionString="metadata=res://*/GenusEFModel.csdl|res://*/GenusEFModel.ssdl|res://*/GenusEFModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=D-SQL203;initial catalog=Genus_AIS_TaskDev_SB4;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Code to retrieve the connection string:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    ConnectionStringSettings genusSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Genus_Connection_String"];
    if (genusSettings == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(genusSettings.ConnectionString))
    {
        throw new Exception("Fatal error: Missing connection string 'Genus_Connection_String' in web.config file");
    }
    string genusConnectionString = genusSettings.ConnectionString;
    EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityConnectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(genusConnectionString);
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlConnectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(entityConnectionStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString);
    string genusSqlServerName = sqlConnectionStringBuilder.DataSource;
    string genusDatabaseName = sqlConnectionStringBuilder.InitialCatalog;

    Console.WriteLine("genusSqlServerName = " + genusSqlServerName);
    Console.WriteLine("genusDatabaseName = " + genusDatabaseName);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you were to setup userid and password within the connection string, you would be able to retrieve them as below:

```
string userID = sqlConnectionStringBuilder.UserID;
string password = sqlConnectionStringBuilder.Password;
```